# Running jdeprscan with specific JDK

Tags: java, jar, compatibility, java-11, jdeprscan

I found out about jdeprscan and there is something that is bugging me about following command

```
jdeprscan --class-path classes --release 8 c:\jars\activation-1.1.jar
```

In here ( from what I believe I understood ) I am running specific jar with specific JDK version which is JDK8 in this example
But if I run

```
jdeprscan --class-path classes --release 11 c:\jars\activation-1.1.jar
```

and it will let me know for some deprecated methods, 
but question that I am asking, will it run the JAR with JDK11, and if that specific JAR is not compatible with JDK11, will it thrown an error?

Comment: *JAR is not compatible with JDK11*, could you explain what incompatibility are you talking about?

Comment: On a different note, `--release 11` would only work with `jdeprscan` version 11 and above.

Comment: For example, activation-1.1.jar does not work with JDK11, but it needs for example activation-3.1.jar. Will it throw an error if I provide it jar that cannot run on that specific release?
And yes, I am running jdeprscan using JDK11, I figured that out.